# bootstrap table display differently between chrome and firefox

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, google-chrome, firefox

I have a table built on bootstrap 2.3.2:

```
<table class="main-table" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="5">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                      <td colspan="3" style="height:50px;">
                        <div id="top-toolbar">
                            <input type="hidden" id="active-date" value="<joda:format value="${activeDate}" pattern="yyyy-MM-dd" />" />
                            <input type="text" class="datepicker" id="formatted-date" value="<joda:format value="${activeDate}" pattern="EEEE dd, MM yyyy" />" 
                            readonly="readonly" />
                            <div class="float-right">
                                <button id="show-new-reservation" value="${outlet.id}" class="ro-button">Add new reservation</button>
                                <c:if test="${currentDate eq activeDate}">
                                    <button id="show-add-walkin" value="${outlet.id}" class="ro-button">Add new walk-in</button>
                                </c:if>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                      </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                      <td><div class="reservations-title"><h2>Upcoming</h2></div></td>
                      <td><div class="reservations-title"><h2>Present</h2></div></td>
                      <td><div class="reservations-title"><h2>Done</h2></div></td>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
```

I tried to change the display to display:table-row for the head but nothing changed, the header row in chrome displays correctly:

[image: Chrome]

In Firefox:

[image: Firefox]

Any help,

Comment: Can you please post the complete, re-producible code, and maybe even add a live example somewhere? Right now, the code you posted is just a snippet that does not even contain the `<tbody>`, let alone any CSS rules.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because firefox don't get table height style in css stylesheet or inline style, I set the height value in the height attribute for each `<td>`

`<td height="650">`

and that worked for me on chrome and firefox.

Hope this will help someone,